# Speed up file copying on a USB drive

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have a USB drive with the following folder structure

```
<root of USB>
--  folder1
    -- folder1a
         -- file1ai
         -- file1aii
         -- file1aiii
    -- folder1b
         -- ...
    -- ...
--  folder2
    -- folder2a
    -- folder2b
    -- ...
--  folder3
    -- folder3a
    -- folder3b
    -- ...
```

Programmatically I need to rearrange the folders on the USB drive as follows

```
<root of USB>
-- new folder
    -- folder1a
    -- folder1b
    -- ...
    -- folder2
       -- folder2a
       -- folder2b
       -- ...
    -- folder3
       -- folder3a
       -- folder3b
       -- ...
```

The code sample here works great https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx BUT it is super slow when there are a huge number of folders involved e.g. when folder1 has 1000 sub-folders (folder1a, folder1b etc), total size of folder1 is ~4MB (~12MB on disk) - these sizes are constant. The copy operation for all folders combined takes upwards of 25 minutes. Is there any way to speed up this operation? I'm hoping there is some super clever way of renaming the folders/manipulating the allocation table/whatever to make this happen.

Notes:

- The input and final rearranged output needs to be on the USB drive -
  this is a sneakernet setup.
- The USB drive is FAT32 or NTFS with 4GB size. We have tried USB 3.0 with no improvement in speed.

Comment: How should this ever be faster then when you do this by hand via WindowsExplorer or similar? I doubt this works, it simply depends on speed of USB. To use USB3.0 you have to have a pluggable USB-device (such as a stick) AND a reader for this (your computer needs USB3.0 also). Pluggin a 3.0-device onto a 2.0-interface will not improve anything.

Comment: Copy the whole in the HDD, reorder and copy back ?

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately the speed gains are lost in the copy back-forth to HDD.

Comment: What's the total size of the data on the USB key? what model is it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The copy operation for all folders combined takes upwards of 25 minutes.

Why are you copying files?  If you move a file on the same device to another folder, the only thing that needs to change is the Allocation Table (FAT/NTFS).  I would recommend using [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a66fkad(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Directory.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Good observation about superior efficiency of moving, but actually the allocation table (FAT) or bitmap (NTFS) does not need to change, only the directories.